# MySQL UNION ALL under phpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin show syntax error with red X

"unrecognized statement type (near ALL)

sql runs, but ignores 2nd select.

same select runs fine under Navicat

thanks for any help on this

```
SELECT  tr.amount amnt, 'cc'
FROM re_rental_deal rd
JOIN ar_payment_credit_card cc ON rd.id = cc.re_rental_deal_id
JOIN ar_transaction tr on tr.id = cc.ar_transaction_id
WHERE rd.closed = 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT tr2.amount, 'ccr'
FROM re_rental_deal rd2
JOIN ar_credit_card_reversal ccr ON rd2.id = ccr.re_rental_deal_id
JOIN ar_transaction tr2 on tr2.id = ccr.ar_transaction_id
WHERE rd2.closed = 1
```

Comment: It appears to be a valid SQL statement. Maybe your client is treating the empty line (or two consecutive line ends) as a statement terminator. Try taking out the blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Trying with 4.6.2 (the current release version) I don't get any syntax errors. Probably you're using an older version where there was a problem with the way the linter was parsing some statements. I suggest upgrading your phpMyAdmin installation.